# Precise timestamps on IO events llinux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gpio, i2c

In a piece of Linux userspace software that takes measurements over I2C and uses GPIO, I would like to get precise timestamps on events. I do not want to see the jitter of task-switching.

In the case of I2C, I would like to get the precise time at which a read completes.
In the case of GPIO, I would like to get the precise time at which an edge was present on the pin.

Basically I'm thinking about something similar to the packet capture timestamps that are available, but for other kernel subsystems.

Is such a thing available?

Comment: From user space, I/O and time are separate calls that could have a gap between them. A custom kernel module could perform the I/O and return it with the time without a delay.

Comment: It is simply impossible to achieve, you need another bus (than i2c) and another OS (than Linux). Otherwise you will have an unpredictable gap in your “precise” timestamps. Or do you have a microcontroller to get that and only then sent via i2c to the host OS?

Comment: @0andriy I get the OS part, and that's kind of what this is about. Since we can obtain precise timestamps for network packets, I figure it should also be possible with any other subsystem. Just grab a timestamp in the kernel at a predefined moment. 
I don't see why you say I2C is the wrong bus for this.